# IMAP, PHP returns no messeges

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I have a connection to the server with my username and password. It connects with a resource id of 2. it displays the status correctly, listing the amount of unread emails in the inbox, recent mail etc. But when it comes to the imap_num_msg() function, I pass in the correct argument but it returns 0. What am I doing wrong for it to return 0?

```
 <?php        
  $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx",   OP_HALFOPEN)
or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

   $list = imap_list($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "*");
   if (is_array($list)) {
   foreach ($list as $val) {
    echo imap_utf7_decode($val) . "\n";
   }
} else {
echo "imap_list failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
}

 $status = imap_status($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", SA_ALL);
 if ($status) {
   echo "Messages:   " . $status->messages    . "<br />\n";
   echo "Recent:     " . $status->recent      . "<br />\n";
   echo "Unseen:     " . $status->unseen      . "<br />\n";
   echo "UIDnext:    " . $status->uidnext     . "<br />\n";
   echo "UIDvalidity:" . $status->uidvalidity . "<br />\n";
  } else {
    echo "imap_status failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
  }
  $numMessages = imap_num_msg($mbox);

 if ($numMessages) { 
   echo $numMessages;
 } else {
    echo "imap_status failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
 }
imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, the solution was to set the flag in the imap_open() function to OP_READONLY which opens the mailbox.

```
 <?php     
     $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", OP_READONLY, 1)
or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());
 ?>
```